# Why does the App Readiness Service cause black screen with mouse cursor after login?

Tags: windows-10, login, services, black-screen-of-death

recently, one of my computers running Windows 10 build 1803 failed to completely login any user on that machine, i.e. a user would login, and then a blck screen with only a mouse cursor appears, nothing else. Using Ctrl Alt Delete you could start taskmanager and a commandprompt, and open services.msc.

Since I found that some PCs suffer from that issue caused by the App Readiness Serivce, I disabled that service, and instantly the complete desktop appeared, without a reboot.

I checked some internet ressources, especially this article:
https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-explains-windows-10-black-screen-login-issue-working-fix/
which states that this issue is mainly caused by the following registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\Applications beginning with:

```
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.
Microsoft.VCLibs.
```

However, none of these keys is present on my system, and my Windows build 1803 is rather new, I only saw reports about that behaviour for older builds.

So my question simply is: why am I affected by this bug, and how can I solve it without leaving the app readiness service disabled all the time. Are there more known details from Microsoft why whis happens at all?